# Search for a text in a pdf file and return the coordinates if the text exist

Tags: c#, itext

I am trying to search for a text in a pdf file and return the coordinates if the text exist. I was researching the net and find out that this can be done with the itextsharp library.

I found this code and I am trying to modify it to meet my requirements. How can I pass my file to this class.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var testFile = @"test.pdf";
        //Create an instance of our strategy
        var t = new MyLocationTextExtractionStrategy("test");

        //Parse page 1 of the document above
        using (var r = new PdfReader(testFile))
        {
            var ex = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(r, 1, t);
        }

        //Loop through each chunk found
        foreach (var p in t.myPoints)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Found text {0} at {1}x{2}", p.Text, p.Rect.Left, p.Rect.Bottom));
        }

        Console.Read();
    }
public class RectAndText
    {
        public iTextSharp.text.Rectangle Rect;
        public String Text;
        public RectAndText(iTextSharp.text.Rectangle rect, String text)
        {
            this.Rect = rect;
            this.Text = text;
        }
    }

    public class MyLocationTextExtractionStrategy : LocationTextExtractionStrategy
    {
        //Hold each coordinate
        public List<RectAndText> myPoints = new List<RectAndText>();

        //The string that we're searching for
        public String TextToSearchFor { get; set; }

        //How to compare strings
        public System.Globalization.CompareOptions CompareOptions { get; set; }

        public MyLocationTextExtractionStrategy(String textToSearchFor, System.Globalization.CompareOptions compareOptions = System.Globalization.CompareOptions.None)
        {
            this.TextToSearchFor = textToSearchFor;
            this.CompareOptions = compareOptions;
        }

        //Automatically called for each chunk of text in the PDF
        public override void RenderText(TextRenderInfo renderInfo)
        {
            base.RenderText(renderInfo);

            //See if the current chunk contains the text
            var startPosition = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.CompareInfo.IndexOf(renderInfo.GetText(), this.TextToSearchFor, this.CompareOptions);

            //If not found bail
            if (startPosition < 0)
            {
                return;
            }

            //Grab the individual characters
            var chars = renderInfo.GetCharacterRenderInfos().Skip(startPosition).Take(this.TextToSearchFor.Length).ToList();

            //Grab the first and last character
            var firstChar = chars.First();
            var lastChar = chars.Last();


            //Get the bounding box for the chunk of text
            var bottomLeft = firstChar.GetDescentLine().GetStartPoint();
            var topRight = lastChar.GetAscentLine().GetEndPoint();

            //Create a rectangle from it
            var rect = new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(
                                                    bottomLeft[Vector.I1],
                                                    bottomLeft[Vector.I2],
                                                    topRight[Vector.I1],
                                                    topRight[Vector.I2]
                                                    );

            //Add this to our main collection
            this.myPoints.Add(new RectAndText(rect, this.TextToSearchFor));
        }
    }
```

Comment: The problem is most likely related to how your input document is structured. So if you can share the file, then I can point out the problem and help you look for a solution.

Comment: Very brief explanation: in a PDF file, it is possible for any word to be written with one rendering instruction per letter, including all possible permutations like 'te', 's', and 't', not necessarily in that order. At the time `RenderText` is called, those separate textchunks aren't collated yet into one word. So anytime the word 'test' is not written together in one rendering instruction, your code will fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks to me like PdfReader accepts a string which is a path to the file you want to read.  So simply change

```
var testFile = @"test.pdf";
```

to point to the file you want to use.  (you may have to add a full path if it is not in the application's working folder)

Comment: Thank you. Yes I am passing the full  path and the search string but the program act like the string is not in the pdf file

Answer (score 0):

omg! Your code so big for that task.
I can recommend much easy solution.
Please look at following

```
//Open PDF document
using (var doc = PdfDocument.Load(@"d:\0\test_big.pdf"))
{
    //Enumerate pages
    foreach(var page in doc.Pages)
    {
        var found = page.Text.Find("text for search", FindFlags.MatchWholeWord, 0);
        if (found == null)
            return; //nothing found
        do
        {
            var textInfo = found.FindedText;
            foreach(var rect in textInfo.Rects)
            {
                float x = rect.left;
                float y = rect.top;
                //...
            }
        } while (found.FindNext());

        page.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: The original poster uses itext (or itextsharp) as indicated in the question tags and question body. You appear to use some other library, or at least the class names you use are not itextsharp class names. Thus, your answer is not appropriate for the question.

Comment: Can you tell what library you are using?

Comment: The post may help to change the way of the poster or maybe help others who looks to find a solution